# Maximum number of indices in amazon rds Postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

Can anyone help me knowing

- Maximum number of indices in Amazon RDS PostgreSQL
- what is the recommended number of indices to use and why?
- Maximum number of columns in Amazon RDS PostgreSQL

I googled these questions but could not get appropriate results. We are having a read-heavy application which involves joining tables. I am exploring amazon rds to understand if it is suitable for our application.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "what is the recommended number of indices to use and why?" --- this question makes no sense. Let your DBA do the job.

Comment: As far as I can tell, that is a "stock" PostgreSQL version, so the limits documented [in the wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#What_is_the_maximum_size_for_a_row.2C_a_table.2C_and_a_database.3F) should apply

Answer (score 0):

Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL runs standard PostgreSQL, so the limits documented for standard PostgreSQL apply. One possibly related limit that could be relevant is maximum instance size: RDS for PostgreSQL supports up to 16TB instances. Also, Amazon Aurora with PostgreSQL compatibility has the same limits, except that instance sizes can go up to 64TB.